# scp files using wildcard. Destination contains result of wildcard

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard, scp

How can a user download many text files at once from a remote host using scp from the terminal using wildcards? In addition, using the result from the wildcard to save the file in the same named directory (lets assume already exists). The remote directories also contain other files with different names. For instance:

4 files in remote host:

```
[Remote-host]:1Dir/File.txt  -> [Local-host]:1Dir/File.txt
[Remote-host]:2Dir/File.txt  -> [Local-host]:2Dir/File.txt
[Remote-host]:3Dir/File.txt  -> [Local-host]:3Dir/File.txt
[Remote-host]:4Dir/File.txt  -> [Local-host]:4Dir/File.txt
```

I have tried using the following to no avail. Please assist

```
scp [remote-host]:'*Dir/File.txt' '*Dir/'
```

Comment: have you tried: `scp user@host:~/*dir/*.txt .`

Comment: @ryekayo Quote that wildcard but yes that should work.

Comment: @Etan Double quotes or single quotes? I never used wildcards with scp..

Comment: Files have to be copied to a single destination. Therefore, you can't use wildcards in the destination. This is similar to how `cp *Src/*.txt *Dest/` doesn't work in any meaningful way. Maybe you intended to copy all `*.txt` files (but nothing else) in subdirs to the current dir, preserving directory structure? `rsync` lets you do that.

Comment: @thatotherguy, yeah that would make sense, what you said that is..

Comment: If the remote folder has other files that we do not wish to download, can rsync exclude them or must everything be synchronised?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to retrieve your files:

`scp user@host:~"/*Dir/*.txt" .`

Or you can try:

`scp user@host:"~/*Dir/*.txt" .`

It really depends on how your user account is mapped in your environment..

Comment: No need to jump in and out of the quotes. Just quote the whole thing. The only thing that might not want to be quoted is the `~` if that needs to expand locally.

Comment: Ok, so like this: ~"/directory*/file*" ?

Comment: I'd use single quotes for preference but it doesn't matter in this case. And yes, I think it likely that the `~` wants to be in the quotes but I'm not sure it matters since I'm not sure the local shell will expand it in that position anyway.

Comment: Sorry, this doesnt quite answer the question. This does not place the identically named files in different folders into folders of the same name on the local system. This would only download all the files to the current location.

Comment: Read that other guys comment, he offers an explanation as to why you can't and an alternative to using scp

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @thatotherguy for the great answer.

For anyone else thats interested, the following command for rsync works

```
rsync -a --include '*Dir/' --include 'File.txt' --exclude '*' [Remote-host]: '\*Dir'
```

This means, include all folders with '*Dir' and files called 'File.txt', exclude everything else. Note that this creates a new directory called *Dir in which all the 1Dir, 2Dir, 3Dir etc. are contained.